# Fetch data from database and count unshipped orders codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from database and show on one page -> website name - number of orders -

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ebay_orders WHERE order_status="Unshipped" ORDER BY webname');
$this->db->where('userid',$userid);

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo '<div style="padding: 0px 10px 0 2px;">';
    echo $row['webname'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $query->num_rows();
    echo '</div><br>';

}
```

Its working but repeating and showing total together like this -

```
ebay1 - 20
ebay1 - 20
ebay1 - 20
ebay1 - 20

ebay2 - 20
ebay2 - 20
ebay2 - 20

ebay3 - 20
ebay3 - 20
ebay3 - 20
```

I want simple method which show data like this -

```
ebay1 - 5
ebay2 - 10
ebay3 - 5
```

Please help!

Comment: Try with `array_count_values($query->result_array());`

Comment: I don't ignite code, but `$query->num_rows();` looks like it won't change in the for-loop. What if your query were `SELECT webname, count(order_status) FROM ebay_orders WHERE order_status="Unshipped" GROUP BY webname ORDER BY webname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query below

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT *, count(id) as total FROM ebay_orders 
                                              WHERE order_status="Unshipped" 
                                              GROUP BY webname 
                                              ORDER BY  webname');
$this->db->where('userid',$userid);
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo '<div style="padding: 0px 10px 0 2px;">';
    echo $row['webname'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $row['total'];
    echo '</div><br>';
}
```

Comment: That works for shorting website name but number of order showing wrong.